# How can We Integrate K net Payment in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

Hello I am working on react native project. Here in this project how should we integrate K-net Payment Integration.

Any SDK's is possible for this please let me give the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

you must write a native module more details [NativeModule](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios#content) you can use K net sdk in bridge module. Also you can check or clone similar payment libraries like

- [react-native-payment-gateway](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-payment-gateway)
- [react-native-paypal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paypal)

then about more detail bridge and native module I recommend [that blog post](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-react-native-bridge-concept-e9526066ddb8)

The alternative solution you can open a web view only for payment 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview (deprecated) => new version supported in the future by react-community https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview

Comment: Okay thanks for that could you give me the more suggestions please